# Clear dropdown when the value in another cell is modified

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to figure out why my script is not working.

I have a sheet called "active unentered invoices" where my master data is housed.  I have a true/false statement in column V and manual data entered in column P of that sheet.

I would like the data validation list in column P to be cleared so it returns to my staff's workflow.

The script below is working but is skipping random rows in column P (90 out of 2000 were skipped) that should also have been cleared.

```
function ClearStatusColumn() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Active UNENTERED Invoices');
  s.getRange('V2:V' + s.getLastRow())
    .getValues()
    .forEach(function (r, i) {
      if (r[0] == 'TRUE') {
        s.getRangeList(["P" + (i + 1)]).clearContent();
      
      }
    });
}
```

BTW, I had looked at the post ["Clear cell based on modification of another cell"](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/106051/clear-cell-based-on-modification-of-another-cell) but was not able to make it work for my purposes.

Comment: what is happening when your code runs?  Are you logging errors in the console?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). `e.range.getSheetByName()` will throw an error because a `Range` object does not have that method. Check [My Executions](https://script.google.com/home/executions) for failed executions, and view those logs to learn more. To fix the code, refer to the resources listed at [Apps Script at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info).

Comment: To be perfectly honest nothing happens.  I did play with it a while and decided to change it entirely. My new one is kind of working BUT for some reason it is skipping random cells that should have been cleared. This is the new script that I came up with:        function ClearStatusColumn() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Active UNENTERED Invoices');
  s.getRange('V2:V' + s.getLastRow())
    .getValues()
    .forEach(function (r, i) {
      if (r[0] == 'TRUE') {
        s.getRangeList(["P" + (i + 1)]).clearContent();
      
      }
    });
}

Answer (score 1):

Chances are that the data contains a mix of text strings like `"TRUE"` or `"true"` and the Boolean value `true`.

Spreadsheet formulas will consider those text strings equal to the Boolean `true` in many contexts, but JavaScript will consider them different.

Letter case and spacing also matters. `"TRUE" !== "true"` and `"TRUE" !== " TRUE"`.

One way to make it work is to coerce the values to lower case text strings where white space has been trimmed, like this:

```
function clearStatusWhenColumnIsTrue() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Active UNENTERED Invoices');
  const targetRange = sheet.getRange('S2:S');
  const targetValues = targetRange.getValues();
  const triggerValues = sheet.getRange('V2:V').getValues().flat();
  const newValues = targetValues.map((row, index) =>
    'true' === String(triggerValues[index]).toLowerCase().trim()
      ? [null]
      : row
  );
  targetRange.setValues(newValues);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Thank you for all of your help.  I was able to get it working, below was my solution.

```
function ClearStatusColumn() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Active UNENTERED Invoices');
  s.getRange('V2:V' + s.getLastRow())
    .getValues()
    .forEach(function (r, i) {
      if (r[0] == 'TRUE') {
        s.getRange(["P" + (i + 2)]).clearContent();
      
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. From [answer] "Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better." Please explain what changes you did to the code.